# How to develop RESTfull web serivces using asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have read about the asp.net Web API ,, but i am not sure if i understand the concept behind the Web API tool. now let say that i have defined a Controller that is derived from the APIController, and i can call this Controller using URL  , and then the Controller will return JSON result to the client,,,

**so does this means that the APIController inside my asp.net MVC web application is exposed as a RESTfull web service?**
BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not your API is considered 'RESTfull' is a question of design, not a question of which libraries/project templates are used. Remember that the whole point of an API is to expose a simple programming interface - how it's implemented behind the scenes isn't important in that regard.

**However**, the WebAPI project template does lend itself well to designing a restfull service due to its built in design principles.

The basic idea behind a REST API is:

- Use HTTP protocol (which WebAPI does, so check)
- Expose a simple API for handling data, usually with POST/GET/PUT/DELETE methods tied to data handling (this is what the WebAPI design lends itself well to)
- Transfer data in an interoperable format (JSON, XML, also easily doable in WebAPI)

It's not much different from designing a REST API using basic MVC Controller/Actions, WebAPI just makes it a bit easier.

Here's a nice video series: http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos/getting-started/your-first-web-api

Answer (score 1):

i just want to add to Anders
REST stands for [Representational state transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)
so basically in architecture you choose a `resource` like `http://www.example.com/USER`
and you instruct the server to do operations on the resource. Specified by the type of `HTTP` request being sent
going by what web api comes out of the box
`POST` - add a new user
`PUT` - edits an existing users info
`GET` - simply retrives user(s) info
`DELETE` - deletes users info
and this is `REST`
The type of data being sent or recived (`JSON` or `XML`). isnt a part of rest specifications. also you can decide incase of asp.net web api data is returned and sent in what format by using 
`Accept` and `Content-Type` headers with your request

Answer (score 0):

Well Apicontroller totaly different from mvc Controller, it comes from Wcf WebApi but made very similar to classic asp.net controllers to developers. The main point is to speed up making restfull services.

So you just assign one more route as always, making some controller than takes querystring and body json(as default) and autoconverts in to Poco classes and returns you another Poco classes serialized to jsion automatically.

Comment: Sorry to correct you, but the ApiController does not come from the WCF Web API project.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wasn't clear. I meant that Apicontroller doesn't extend Controller or even ControllerBase class, it just implement IHttpController